# NetBeans shortcut to go to the file location in the Project Explorer

Tags: netbeans

What is the netbeans shortcut:  when I am on file, If I have to find out the location of the file on the left nav "Project explorer"?

In eclipse we used to have the two sided arrow, if I click on that, It will expand the directories and take us to the location where the file is located.  any similar shortcut for netbeans?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `Ctrl + Shift + 1` combo to select the currently focused editor view's file in the Project Explorer.

FYI you can use the `Ctrl + Shift + 2` combo to select the file in the Files Explorer.

Comment: Just a sidenote, it's Cmd+Shift+1/2 for OS X

Comment: As another note: if you have item (file or folder) in your `Favorites` you also can go to this item in `Projects` tab with the same shortcut.